# how to prevent Blend making auto columns

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, blend

Often when trying to move a control in Blend, Blend starts making auto columns drawing splitting  vertical lines. I am new to Blend and it makes for me difficult 
to move a control while those lines are multiplying non stop. How to disable this behavior ? [image]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to untick "`Show Handles`" or "`Show Selection Preview`" or "`Show Alignment Adorners`" on the `Design` menu in Blend.